# Special class of a set

Tags: analysis

Is there an name for a class of a set (set of subsets of the set) which closed under pairwise intersections and which has the set as element? I mean a class $\mathcal{C}$ of a set $\Omega$ such that $\Omega\in\mathcal{C}$ and $A\cap B\in\mathcal{C}$ for all elements $A$ and $B$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

The property itself is known as the 'finite intersection property', and [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property), sets satisfying such a property are called 'centered systems' or 'filter subbases'

Comment: Note that one can generalise this to $\kappa$-complete filters which are closed under "$\kappa$-sized intersections".

Comment: Next station: measurable cardinals :p

Comment: @ac15 I saw the definition, and for the finite intersection property, it is not necessary to have the set as an element

Comment: @RataMágica [Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(set_theory)) are the objects you desire. They have the finite intersection property and always contain the set itself.

Comment: To give some more context, they are in some sense the abstraction of "large sets" in the sense that "the intersection of large sets is still large".

Comment: @RataMágica given that taking intersections of the 'bigger set' with its subsets always returns the latter, it seems immaterial whether the bigger set is in fact an element of the class or not: the available structure can't tell the difference

Comment: @ac15 what do you mean by "immaterial"?

Comment: @VincentBatens, it seem that filters have a third property, I want to know a name for a class with only the two properties asked

Comment: Then I ask myself why exactly you are looking for such a structure? What is the motivation behind your question?

Comment: The finite intersection property usually refers to having nonempty finite intersections, not closure under finite intersections (though a collection of nonempty sets closed under finite intersections will have the fip, of course).

Comment: @VincentBatens, my motivation is curiosity, and the fact that if you add to this class the property of being closed under complements you get and algebra (a good starting point for measure theory), and if you add to this class the property of being closed under arbitrary unions you get a topology (a good starting point for Topology). Furthermore, maybe one motivation is that I don't want to invent a term if there is one

Comment: I don't know a structure that doesn't ask for the last statement. I guess people call it just a set that is closed under intersections, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @RataMágica There are $\pi$-systems, which is just closure under binary intersections. Similarly to what ac15 said above, since we’re usually interested in what $\sigma$-algebra or topology or filter these things generate, the extra condition that we need the whole set (or equivalently closure under nullary intersections) doesn’t matter much.